# add object to existing JSON file JAVA

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to add a new JSON object inside cars.json in "carTypes"

How would I go about doing this?
Im able to fetch data from cars.json but don't know how to add data to it

My current cars.json file

```
    "carTypes": [
    {
      "model": "toyota",
      "make": "corolla",
      "year": "2005"
      
    }
  ],
```

How I want it to be

```
"carTypes": [
        {
          "model": "toyota",
          "make": "corolla",
          "year": "2005"
          
        },
       {
          "model": "civic",
          "make": "honda",
          "year": "2017"
          
        }
      ],
```

Comment: Could you please show what have tried so far in code?

Comment: What JSON library do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

and you already have the content of your first snippet inside a `JsonNode` that you loaded from somewhere,

```
JsonNode carTypes = mapper.readTree(...);
```

then you should:

```
ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) jsonNode.get("carTypes"); //<-- 1) convert the node into ArrayNode
ObjectNode objNode = mapper.createObjectNode(); //<-- 2) create a new object node
objNode.put("model", "civic"); //<-- add your attributes to the new object node
array.put(objNode); //<-- put the new node inside the array
```

Then you can convert your array back to `JsonNode` and do whatever you want with your Json.

Comment: im not using object mapper to read json files

Comment: @JdjsnsNdjsnss in this case you should specify what framework you're using in the question and using tags. The above solution is based on Jackson (a very standard framework to work with Json).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `org.json` and have loaded the JSON:

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Then you can get to the `"carTypes"` array and add the new element:

```
 JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("carTypes");

 JSONObject hondaCivic17Json = new JSONObject()
         .put("model", "civic")
         .put("make", "honda")
         .put("year", "2017");

 JSONArray newArray = arr.put(hondaCivic17Json);
 JSONObject newJson = obj.put("carTypes", newArray);

 String newJsonStr = newJson.toString();
 System.out.println(newJsonStr);
```

Output:

```
{
  ...
  "carTypes":
    [
     {"year":"2005","model":"toyota","make":"corolla"}, 
     {"year":"2017","model":"civic","make":"honda"}
    ] 
  ...
}
```

You can override the file like this:

```
 Files.write(path, newJson.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: i havent added the files.write part yet but when newJsonStr is printed it prints something else instead of carTypes. i also have enginesTypes in the save json file

Comment: @JdjsnsNdjsnss Of course, because it depends on the JSON structure. You can add the entire JSON and I will edit my answer.